# How to get merge commit SHA for merged pull request?

Tags: github, github-api

There is a related question [GET pull request merge commit sha from pull request number using github api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331524/get-pull-request-merge-commit-sha-from-pull-request-number-using-github-api), yet there is no answer.

According to GitHub API, once Pull Request was merged, it triggers the `pull_request` event with `action: closed`. The event is [also available](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent) from Events API. However, there are only `merged` (which is `true` if the pull request was merged) and deprecated `merge_commit_sha` (SHA of temporary merge commit, not the actual commit by which pull request was merged) fields.

There is also [API for dealing with pull requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request); yet, according to the documentation, it also will only return whether pull request was merged, and what is the temporary commit SHA (in a deprecated field).

Pull request is clearly associated with the merge commit somehow, as commit SHA is shown on pull request page:

[image]

Is there some way to get programmatically SHA of the commit by which pull request was merged to the base, knowing the pull request ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All pull requests are also issues. So you can fetch the [Issue Events](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#events-1) for any Pull Request. With that, there will be a `commit_id`. If that attribute is present with a `merged` attribute then that should be the SHA of the merge commit.

Comment: This actually allows one to get a merge commit number; it is enough to fetch all events for the issue (e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14930/events) and find one with `event: "merged"`. However, this way seems "bad", as one is required to fetch all events to get a commit number (and there could easily be a thousands of events for the single issue); so I'll refrain to accepting your answer right now in case someone will give another one.